# Shout the input

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string that consists entirely of printable ASCII, convert all lowercase letters to their uppercase equivalent. Non-lowercase characters are left untouched.

I am not going to outright ban builtin solutions, but if you are going to post a solution that uses the builtin, please also post one that doesn't in your answer.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins, standard rules apply.

### Test cases

```
input => output

Hello, World! => HELLO, WORLD!
TEST => TEST
1gN0r3 50M3 cH4r4C73r5 => 1GN0R3 50M3 CH4R4C73R5
```

GOOD LUCK GOLFERS!

Comment: I closed this question as a dupe since it's essentially converting a string to a specific case, the only addition being that built-ins are added, which doesn't make this much different in my opinion. If you don't agree with the closure, you can vote to reopen this question.

Comment: SQL WOULD LOVE THIS CHALLENGE.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Just got an answer which works for that question but not this one: [(JavaScript) `a=>a.replace(/[A-Z]/g,a=>parseInt(a,36).toString(36))`](https://tio.run/##DY1BC4IwGIb/ip22wZrGtE4GEYEd6qIQZB4@5hzK2sbn6O/bTi/Pc3jeBX6wKpxD3Ds/6m2qN6jPIFAHC0rTvL/s30NueLIBcNV3FylweWQi@jbi7AxNwDbl3eqtFtYb2pNGW@t59vJoxx3hpLu1XZqDeRYos6p4yEw1JZbXk8SKDOILgaaHiQJjYvGzo@TjSMr@AQ)

Comment: @tsh That actually lowercases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) & [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable) (and probably others), 1 byte

```
u
```

**Try it:** [Japt](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=dQ==&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi)  |  [05AB1E](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/9P9/w3Q/gyJjBVMDX2OFZA@TIhNnc@MiUwA)  |  [2sable](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f@/9P9/w3Q/gyJjBVMDX2OFZA@TIhNnc@MiUwA)

Thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for pointing out the polyglots.

---

### Japt Without Built-in, 16 bytes

```
c_¨#a©Z§#z?Z-H:Z
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=Y1+oI2GpWqcjej9aLUg6Wg==&input=IkhlbGxvLCBXb3JsZCEi)

Comment: [Polyglot with 05AB1E](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/9P9/w3Q/gyJjBVMDX2OFZA@TIhNnc@MiUwA)

Comment: [Also polyglot with 2sable](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f@/9P9/w3Q/gyJjBVMDX2OFZA@TIhNnc@MiUwA). Sorry for finding them 1 by 1 :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 9 bytes

```python
str.upper
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzv7ikSK@0oCC16H9BUWZeiUaahpJHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqikqbmfwA) or [Verify all test cases.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzv7ikSK@0oCC16H9BUWZeiUaahpJHak5Ovo5CeH5RToqikqYmF1wmxDU4BEXAMN3PoMhYwdTA11gh2cOkyMTZ3LjIFKjkPwA)**

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

Saved many bytes thanks to @FelipeNardiBatista.

```python
lambda k:''.join(chr(ord(c)-32*(c>'_'))for c in k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbSl1dLys/M08jOaNII78oRSNZU9fYSEsj2U49Xl1TMy2/SCFZITNPIVvzf0FRZl6JRpqGUqKjR2pOTr6OQnh@UU5KVZSikqYmF1w2xDU4BEXAMN3PoMhYwdTA11gh2cOkyMTZ3LjIFKjkPwA)

Comment: [50 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbSl1dLys/M08jOaNII78oRSNZU9fYSEsj2U49Xl1TMy2/SCFZITNPIVvzf0FRZl6JRpqGUqKjR2pOTr6OQnh@UU5KVZSikqYmF1w2xDU4BEXAMN3PoMhYwdTA11gh2cOkyMTZ3LjIFKjkPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
rQ1
```

Equivalent to `str.upper` in python.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 6 bytes

**5 bytes code + 1 for `-p`.**

```perl
$_=uc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3rY0@f9/j9ScnHwdhfD8opwURa4Q1@AQLsN0P4MiYwVTA19jhWQPkyITZ3PjItN/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 18 bytes

```
s=>s.toUpperCase()
```

Comment: [Without builtins.](https://tio.run/##PY5dC4IwGIX/it20DXKo06JIIyTwpm4UurDAl/mRMjeZ0t9fu6iuDs/h4XAGeMPMdT8trlR1Y0wbQ5yUlFJ40hEmbClfdC872mo1pi/QqfWw7YHyL50XTEiy367h6AfsBC4LDkAIHVQvq8pwJWclGipUh0uUNUKojXNXWtQrtEHFJS9s@N3N08yJvCtzeBbqMN0xHaH/iRb/FjF6SESI@QA)

Comment: Thanks, @ThePirateBay; I was about to port my 16 byte Japt solution, which would have been exactly what you posted, when the challenge got dupe-hammered, so I just moved on.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 11 bytes

```
ToUpperCase
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Œu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opNL///8bpvsZFBkrmBr4Giske5gUmTibGxeZAgA)